# nodejs express validator seperate file problem

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I want to make a Register file and add it to my router.post('/register ..');

But I got one Problem.

He shows me a unexpceted " , " . Can anyone help me?

register.js

```
'use strict';

const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const register = 
body('email').trim().isEmail().isLength({ min: 5, max: 100 }),
body('url').trim().isLength({ min: 5, max: 100}), async (req, res) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

        const data = errors.mapped();

        res.status(200).json({
            data
        });

    }
}


module.exports = register;
```

I want to make the file that I can write this:

```
const register = require('./register.js');

router.post('/register', register);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// register.js

'use strict';

const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
await body('email').trim().isEmail().isLength({ min: 5, max: 100 }).run(req)
await body('url').trim().isLength({ min: 5, max: 100}).run(req)

const errors = validationResult(req);

if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
   const data = errors.mapped();
   // sends 400 with error data
   return res.status(400).json({data})
  }

 // Process request, generate data and sent to client
 const data = // reference data here
 res.status(200).json({data});
}
```

```js
// routes.js

'use strict'

const router = require('express').Router()

router.post('/register', require('./register'))

module.exports = router
```